# Add multiple dynamic widgets different from each other using listview.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget

I am learning flutter and I am new , can you help me to tell how to add dynamic widgets on screen , these widgets are different from each other
e.g  one dynamic widget having container which contain 4 buttons and other dynamic widget container contain 6 buttons ,
If user want to add container having 6 buttons , he can add  As well as if he want to add 4 button container that can also added in it,
This containers are in either horizontal sequence or vertical sequence

I have done with single type of container but unable to add other type container !!
Please help !!
[image]

Comment: Please put your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [List.generate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html)

Comment: tnx for your guidance can you guide me how to join Stateful Widget1 and Stateful Widget2 through List.generate through Code to make single list for listView.builder

Comment: what do you mean ? i can't understand what are you saying. Do you have any picture about it ?

Comment: I got the solution , tnx for your guidance !!

Answer (score 0):

you have a listWidget, you have to add your blue Containers to that list and then setState
for example, you have a button to add to this list

```
 onTap: () {
listWidge.add(BLUECONTAINER);
setState((){});

}
```